# Does google fonts has Diacritic / Diacritics?

Tags: fonts, font-face, diacritics

I came to a problem with google fonts - I needed to use diacritics, characters like
ěščřžýáíé, ..., When I edited the font page in google font "Pop out" page, it worked, but when I used the default generated code on the "Quick-use" page, diacritics didnt work...

Eventually I found the solution by checking the google "Quick-use" page's source code.

**Solved below...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 2021 EDIT: DON'T CONFUSE NEW "auto-detect" `unicode-range` functionality with a diacritic support! (it is NOT)

Recently there was a new functionality added which resulted in removal of the `subset=...` param, since [most current modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=unicode-range) support [`unicode-range` `@font-face` property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range)

However, **don't confuse this with an actual support of all diacritics  in that language set, which this is not**. That one still **depends on each individual font**, meaning **as of 2021, this Answer still stays valid**. Historically, you had to define subsets(that just **may** contain your diacritics/characters) if you didn't want the browser to download all possible subsets, now the browser - if `unicode-range`s are defined properly  - can select those subsets, **that still just MAY**, contain that character automatically for you.

## 2021 interface

## CAUTION: SET DOES 
NOT ALWAYS GUARANTEE ALL CHARS!

### LATIN EXTENDED CAUTION

For example, fact that a font has latin-extended set does **NOT** mean it has **all** [caron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron) / [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(diacritic)) letter-variants - especially "ů" is oftentimes missing...

**I would be very cautious about this for any language that contains diacritics - always test it first with a [Pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram)**

Even interface changed recently, now, in 2021 (February) the steps are following:

1. **Find a [Pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram) = "sentence using every letter of a given alphabet at least once" - to test the whole set of target language at once**
2. go to http://www.google.com/fonts/
3. Somewhere in the middle you should see an input with a placeholder saying "Type something" - if not, it should be the one next to the search, where there's dropdown from which you can select "Custom" (or go to this reset link - https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=&preview.text_type=custom)
4. In the input fill in your [Pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram)
5. Be cautious, check EVERY letter from the Pangram AKA every letter of target alphabet.

### old answer / interface:

Many of them do, to find out wether they do or dont contain your characters go to
http://www.google.com/fonts/ and find your font, open it by "Pop out" button and look for your characters.
If the font contains characters you need, go back and click on "Quick-use" button - this will open the page where you can adjust some options and it will generate a code for your page - something like this:

`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Meie+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Now you have 2 options:

1. You dont care much about the page load - **just add &subset=all to the href attribute** and the link will load all the characters the font has. So you will have something like this:

`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Meie+Script&subset=all' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

2. However if you do care about the page load, you should load only character sets you need - on the google font page which generates the code to use - notice the "2. Choose the character sets you want:" section - there you can use ("Quick-use" page) choose which character sets you will be using and you will get something like

`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Meie+Script&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Notice that now there is a list of character sets in the &subset attribute .

Comment: The Google Font API was recently changed and no longer includes the subset parameter. Because apparently all browser now "know" which subset they need. Do you have any info on how to "teach" my browser that?

Comment: @AdamJagosz In their new CSS - they use `unicode-range` CSS `@font-face` property - **"If the page doesn't use any character in this range, the font is not downloaded; if it uses at least one, the whole font is downloaded. "** - really good support in modern browsers - https://caniuse.com/?search=unicode-range - so you **don't teach it, you just update** the browser if it doesn't already know... I've also updated the answer to reflect those changes, thanks for the reminders ;)